# What's the difference between "really have had" and "have really had"?

Tags: differences, adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

In a sentence, what's the difference between "he must really have had a rough day" and "he must have really had a rough day"?

Comment: No difference. An intensifying adverb like _really_ can modify an adjective like _rough_ (_He must have had a really rough day_), or it can modify a verb by going after the first or the second auxiliary verb (respectively, _must_ and _have_ here). Either auxiliary placement is fine.

Comment: I agree with @John Lawler with his "He must have had a really rough day!" That sounds best to me. Don

Comment: "Must" muddies the waters here. Remove it from the sentence and both versions become even more equally valid: "He really has had a rough day" / "He has really had a rough day" (and, for that matter, "He has had a really rough day"). If you're concerned about splitting up "has" and "had"... [don't](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4385) [be](http://thelanguagelady.blogspot.com/2009/02/yes-we-can-split-auxiliaries.html).